# Jquery UI, how can I make draggable always revert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Ive been looking for this answer for hours, but I cant find it.

I am using Jquery UI and I would like to ALWAYS revert to original position if dropped or not.

If it is dropped, I would like it to execute the following code, 'alert($(ui.draggable).attr("id"));'

I know this answer is probably very easy, however i am struggling. Thank you very much for looking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the revert option and set it to true and also the handle callback function and do what you want in there

```
$("#myDraggable").draggable({
    revert: true
});

$("#myDroppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui){
        alert($(ui.draggable).attr("id"));
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if these two will work together but you can give it a shot! By that I mean if revert is set to true I'm not sure if the drop handler will ever get called.

Comment: I have tried this before but it didn't work. It would stick onto the droppable. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Oh, I some how got it to work, I cant believe I missed it. Thanks so much.

Comment: It works, however it only reverts when I drop it in the droppable, however it doesn't revert in any other situation.

Comment: Anymore ideas? I need a combination of revert: "valid"  and revert: "invalid";

Comment: I thought that was what revert: true was supposed to do.